# Sort Elements in list based on date attribute and remove all old entries-java

Tags: arraylist, sorting

need to remove elements from an ArrayList based on one of its attributes
I have an arraylist alElement containing elements like:

```
   [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <SPLSCustnumRel ConID="1961262402" Customer="730206"
           Party="125854302" StartDate="2010-01-20-00.00.00.000000" />
          , <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <SPLSCustnumRel ConID="1113415796" Customer="730206"
            Party="125854302" StartDate="2011-10-05-00.00.00.000000" />
          , <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <SPLSCustnumRel ConID="19612402" Customer="730206"
            Party="125854302" StartDate="2012-01-20-00.00.00.000000" />
      ]
```

This was previously unsorted. I have sorted this arraylist based on StartDate like :

```
        Collections.sort(alElement, new Comparator<YFCElement>() {

                    public int compare(YFCElement o1, YFCElement o2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        return o1.getAttribute("StartDate").compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getAttribute("StartDate"));
                    }

                });
```

No i want toremove all element but the one with the most recent Start Date .I tried comparing the date inside the sort but it is not working. 
Any help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a PriorityQueue and dequeue the tail then clear the queue and insert it back.
Actually, you can do that with your list... it's simpler

Answer (score 0):

Hi actually i have figured a work around. Since I have already sorted the list with element with Most Recent StartDate being the last Element, I am removing all except the last element in the list by just writing a line like:

```
    alElement.subList(0, alElement.size()-1).clear();
```

This solves my purpose.